# How to integrate Razorpay in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am trying to integrate razorpay but got confused in third step.
Please check the link and provide the solution.

https://razorpay.com/docs/payment-gateway/web-integration/custom/

Comment: Have you tried any of the steps in this documentation?  What did razorpay seem to do when you got to step 3?   Here on stackoverflow, we do expect that you have tried to solve some of this before asking for help/answers, not just reading documentation and asking us for free code.  People here won't usually just provide solutions like that, or post "how to" articles.  But if you've tried something and are stuck, we are usually glad to help you solve errors or problems.

Comment: You haven't explained what confused you or what you tried.  Please give more detail.

Comment: Thnx for your comment i have solved this.